# Unable to get tensorflow working on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

I am trying to get tensor flow on my Mac OS X Yosemite.  I tried it in a number of ways, all of which result in an error.

1. Method #1: using virtualenv.  When I get to the

   ```
   pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl
   ```

   I get

   ```
    BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
   ```
2. Method #2: using Anaconda.  Again, when within the anaconda environment I do

   ```
   pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.6.0-py2-none-any.whl
   ```

I get an error, although a different one this time:

```
    SLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

3. Method #3: using bazel.  Numerous dependency issues - e.g.,

   ```
   bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

   ... no such package '@jpeg_archive// ...
   ... no such package '@png_archive// ...
   ```

   etc.

   Has anyone been able to successfully build tensorflow on a mac (that's sitting behind a corporate firewall, btw - maybe that's part of the problem).  Any insight would be much appreciated.

   Thanks!

   Natalia

Comment: Have you tried using docker based installation? seems painless to me.

Comment: Thanks S_kar.  Yes, I tried docker but couldn't get docker itself to work, never mind use it for tensorflow - when I simply start docker, either in a terminal or through Kitematic, I get "fatal error: runtime: bsdthread_register error".

Comment: I do not use mac, But [this](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/109) might help you getting rid of that error.

Comment: Yeah, the websense issue... I suspect that's what's causing my SSL issue as well (see method #2, w/anaconda).  Unfortunately, corporate policy makes it impossible for me to stop websense.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing secure to `http`, something like `sudo pip install --upgrade http://...` instead (and also, you should try checking `pip` version too)

Comment: Tried that - then it keeps regressing to the "BadZipFile" error.